# How to password-protect a whole Bugzilla website

Tags: bugzilla

I am doing a software project, together with people in other states. I just set up a Bugzilla website (Bugzilla 4.4.9, Apache 2.4, and Windows 7 Professional 64-bit) and it is available on the internet. I have disabled Bugzilla's self-registration of user accounts.

Now I would like to further restrict the website access (such as search and view bug reports) only to those people who have Bugzilla accounts and have signed in. Put it another way, I don't want anonymous visitors to be able to use the website or search engines to index the site. Is this something doable without modifying Bugzilla's code, which is bad in many ways? If yes, how?

If brute-force modification of Bugzilla's code is the only way, I would very appreciate any info about which files to modify or, if available, the details. I am new to Bugzilla, and I never coded with Perl.

Googled for the answer, but did not find any.

Comment: You question doesn't seem to be related to programming. You should post it to [SuperUser.com](http://superuser.com/) instead.

Comment: @Lars Kristensen: I wouldn't expect to see a question about Bugzilla on Super User.

Answer (score 1):

I feel I got the answer:

1. sign into the system as the maintainer
2. Go to Administration, Parameters, User Authentication.
3. Check requirelogin

All the above does is only the homepage is visible to visitors, but no search of results or website browser is allowed.

Cheers.